# PHP extension stats

Tags: php, windows, math, xampp, pecl

I'm using PHP in combination with Xampp and have installed the extension stats for Windows (https://pecl.php.net/package/stats/2.0.3/windows). Phpinfo says everything works fine. Stats is enabled. Nevertheless I am getting the error message

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function stats_rand_gen_ibinomial(),

when I am using the function stats_rand_gen_ibinomial, which is documented here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stats-rand-gen-ibinomial.php.

Have you got experiences with these extension?

Comment: *Phpinfo says everything works fine.* can you show us?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In php.ini i have added the following line: extension=stats

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was that you need to restart the apache but the output in the screen seems to be be ok, then I executed ">php -m"  and the extension was listed but when I run a script calling stats_rand_gen_ibinomial() it fails(exactly what you describe).

I download the source code 2.0.3 and 2.0.0 and the method is not **included**!!, the same with 1.0.5 and 1.0.4. **The last version when the method does exist is : 1.0.3.**

You can download all the versions here https://pecl.php.net/package/stats and look for the last one with that method definition. But the conclusion is that for some reason that method is not included . I ignore the reason.